# Set app to use cellular network rather than WiFi in android 5+

Tags: java, android, networking, mobile, connection

We have an app  we are making that needs to switch to cellular for some requests even when WiFi is connected. 
According to the `ConnectionManager` documentation these following methods are now deprecated, but is not so clear on what to use instead.

```
  public void useMobileNetworkMode(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager  cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    cm.setNetworkPreference(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
}

public void useDefaultNetworkMode(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager  cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    cm.setNetworkPreference(ConnectivityManager.DEFAULT_NETWORK_PREFERENCE);

}
```

Do these methods still work in android 5/6? and if anyone has info or something to replace these methods with I would be very grateful!

---

Ok little bit more on the problem :)
I have managed to investigate ConnectivityManager and can see the networks using :

```
                     Network networkToUse = null;
    Network[] networks;
    networks = cm.getAllNetworks();
    for (Network network : networks) {
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getNetworkInfo(network);
        Log.e("NETWORKINFO", ni.getType() + "   " + ni.getExtraInfo());
        if (ni.getType()== ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
            Log.e("NETWORKINFO", "isWifi");
            if (ni.isConnected()) {
                Log.e("NETWORKINFO", "and is connected");
                if (networkToUse == null) {
                    networkToUse = network;
                }
            }
        }
        if (ni.getType()== ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            Log.e("NETWORKINFO", "HasMobile");
            if (ni.isConnected()) {
                Log.e("NETWORKINFO", "and is connected");
                networkToUse = network;
            }
        }
    }
```

It is here I kind of get stuck because I can't logically see a way of telling the app to use one of these networks when performing a `HttpsURLConnection` from `URL.openLink();`.

---

UPDATE: 
I have just noticed that the mobile one disappears shortly after WiFi connects. There is a moment where I get both but not for long.

I have also tried this:

```
    final ConnectivityManager connection_manager =
            (ConnectivityManager)httpsClient.getCheckoutController().getCheckout().getCurrentActivity().getApplication().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkRequest.Builder request = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
    request.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR);

    connection_manager.registerNetworkCallback(request.build(), new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onAvailable(Network network) {
            Log.e("NETWORKINFO", "FOUND A CELLULAR NETWORK " + connection_manager.getNetworkInfo(network));
        }
    });

    request = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
    request.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
    connection_manager.registerNetworkCallback(request.build(), new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {


        @Override
        public void onAvailable(Network network) {
            Log.e("NETWORKINFO", "FOUND A WIFI NETWORK "+connection_manager.getNetworkInfo(network));
        }
    });
```

but as with the "list" of networks" in previous try I only ever 1 callback, even if mobile data is on as well.

---

UPDATE;
Ok I seem to see mobile sometimes using above method. but it seems to create API level spaghetti hell. It sometimes also takes a very long time for the mobile callback to fire. I wonder if this is because it has to wake up the cellular modem and wait for it's handshake or something?

---

UPDATE;
I had another possible suggestion using Sockets (something I have little experience with..)

Does anyone know if it is possible to build a CELLULAR SSL connection socket to do https requests using `HttpsURLConnection.getSocketFactory()` and `SSLSocket` ?

Any info would be very welcome in this week long quest :D

---

UPDATE:
Found a good and categorical answer from someone at google:
[How to stay connected through mobile network after WIFI is connected on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29835240/how-to-stay-connected-through-mobile-network-after-wifi-is-connected-on-android)

However after implementation, i get a network callback for the mobile but when i open URL connection and perform a request it seems to get stuck for ages (about 4 minutes) before i get the response.

I have a Huawei 5.0.1 phone, which is the highest i have available. Obviously this is not good. However it is not tested on 5.1 galaxy S6 and works.. so could be the phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a good and categorical answer from someone at google: How to stay connected through mobile network after WIFI is connected on Android?

(Link is in edited info above)

However after implementation, i get a network callback for the mobile but when i open URL connection and perform a request it seems to get stuck for ages (about 4 minutes) before i get the response.

I have a Huawei 5.0.1 phone, which is the highest i have available. Obviously this is not good. However it is not tested on 5.1 galaxy S6 and works.. so could be the phone.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Android documentation it is no longer working in Android version 5 and above.

> This method was deprecated in API level 21.
>
> Functionality has been removed as it no longer makes sense, with many more >than two networks - we'd need an array to express preference. Instead we >use dynamic network properties of the networks to describe their >precedence.

Comment: Yes i saw that, I found out after a some hair tearing what that actually means (a ref or two might be nice google :D )..
Anyway,  I have done some new experiments and have some newer problems posted above. :)