# Send data through wifi (no internet) and mobile data at the same time

Tags: android, sockets, android-wifi, android-networking, network-interface

I'm developing an application that connects to a hardware device through WiFi (Generated by the device) to realize local requests and retrieve device's data and realize requests to a backend server through Data Mobile at the same time.

Unfortunately, when I run the application, I have this error:

```
No connection with server exception.
```

Because I think that the request to the local server (hardware device) is through Data Mobile too.

Is there any way to have two connections at the same time and each request works through its corresponding connection? I have reviewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35152417/send-data-through-wifi-no-internet-when-mobile-data-on) before, but it does not help me.

Thanks.