# Android Studio - Android 12 wifi icon hided by mobile data when no internet via wifi

Tags: android-wifi, mobile-data

My app uses wifi to connect to devices, no internet, however when mobile data is active it hides wifi status/icon when wifi has no internet.

I need the wifi status to broadcast receiver knows if wifi is connected or not.
I dont know how enable this staus programatically under Android studio.

When i disable mobile data, everything works ok.

Answer (score 0):

Solved !!
link:
[Send data through wifi (no internet) when mobile data on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35152417/send-data-through-wifi-no-internet-when-mobile-data-on)

Need set default network as wifi to send data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).