# Access internet through mobile data when wifi is connected to OBD in marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, connectivity

I have both **WIFI** and **mobile data** enabled. In wifi I have connected to an **OBD** which has no internet connection but will stream some data if connected. In order to start that stream I used the below code:

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getCurrentActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo ni = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (SDK_INT >= LOLLIPOP) {
            NetworkRequest.Builder request = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
            request.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);

            connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(request.build(), new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                    if (SDK_INT >= LOLLIPOP && SDK_INT < M) {
                        ConnectivityManager.setProcessDefaultNetwork(network);
                    } else if (SDK_INT >= M) {
                        connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

I got the code from this answer.

[How to stay connected through mobile network after WIFI is connected on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29835240/how-to-stay-connected-through-mobile-network-after-wifi-is-connected-on-android#answer-29837637)

When it comes to get the active network into at `connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo()` I get the network type as **MOBILE[LTE]**. Once it hits the `onAvailable` method, whenever I try to get the active network type it says **WIFI[]**.

After this the stream gets started. Now I want the **mobile data** to be activated again since it is enabled. So I tried the same code after the stream started by just replacing `TRANSPORT_WIFI` with `TRANSPORT_CELLULAR` in `request.addTransportType`.

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getCurrentActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo ni = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (SDK_INT >= LOLLIPOP) {
            NetworkRequest.Builder request = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
            request.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR);

            connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(request.build(), new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                    if (SDK_INT >= LOLLIPOP && SDK_INT < M) {
                        ConnectivityManager.setProcessDefaultNetwork(network);
                    } else if (SDK_INT >= M) {
                        connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

What happens is, when I debug this process, `NetworkInfo` always has the WIFI connection even after it hits the `onAvailable` method.

Please pinpoint if I was wrong somewhere or am I missing something.

Comment: I'm not sure this will not affect the OBD stream (never tried it), but did you try setting 'connectivityManager.setNetworkPreference(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);'  after the stream started?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am trying to do something very similar.

Comment: Were you able to get this sorted out?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. But we moved to another solution where we don't need the WiFi for the OBD. Couldn't find any solution for this problem.