# ConnectivityManager Network is null when specifying to use only wifi

Tags: java, android, android-connectivitymanager

I am trying to store a wifi network (and eventually cellular network) through ConnectivityManager for use later in my program to send data specifically through a local Wifi or cellular network simultaneously. I have followed this post ([Make Android simultaneously use WiFi to talk to a device and mobile data to talk to a server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24429190/make-android-simultaneously-use-wifi-to-talk-to-a-device-and-mobile-data-to-talk) and [How to stay connected through mobile network after WIFI is connected on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29835240/how-to-stay-connected-through-mobile-network-after-wifi-is-connected-on-android)) to try and get it running. However the `mWifiNetwork` is null. Using debug mode the variable `mWifiNetwork` shows up as `"108"` then when the '''onAvailable''' method is complete the variable turns back to null. Not sure why the variable is not storing the network correctly.

I created a class forceWifiNetwork that is called in onResume

**forceWifiNetwork.java**

```
public class forceWifiNetwork {

    //setting up a context variable and method to use "getSystemService"
    // this way we do not need to extend MainActivity class to this class
    // But when we initialize this class in main activity we will have to pass in "this" to the class as a parameter

    Context mContext;
    private ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback mWifiNetworkCallback;
    public Network mWifiNetwork;
    final ConnectivityManager manager;



    public forceWifiNetwork(Context mContext){
        this.mContext = mContext;
        manager = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    }




    public void cellConnect(){

        if (mWifiNetworkCallback == null){

            // Init only once
            mWifiNetworkCallback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback(){
                @Override
                public void onAvailable(final Network network){
                    try{
                        //Save this network for later use
                        mWifiNetwork = network;
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        Log.i("onAvailable ERROR","Error in onAvailable method");
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        NetworkRequest.Builder wifiBuilder;
        wifiBuilder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
        //set the transport type to do wifi
        wifiBuilder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
        //wifiBuilder.addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET);
        manager.requestNetwork(wifiBuilder.build(),mWifiNetworkCallback);


    }

}
```

**onResume** (in MainActivity.java)

```
    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        try {
            forceWifiNetwork myWifiNetwork = new forceWifiNetwork(this);
            myWifiNetwork.cellConnect();
            if (myWifiNetwork.mWifiNetwork == null) {
                Log.i("onResume", "mWifiNetwork is null");
            } else {
                Log.i("onResume", "mWifiNetwork is not null");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.i("ERROR IN ONRESUME","error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

I also currently have these permissions in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the initiation of the `forceWifiNetwork` in `onCreate` instead of `onResume`. The `onAvailable` method in the `ConnectivityManager.Networkcallback` I believe may have some underlying Async properties. It would look something like this.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //creating network variables that store wifi and cell networks
        myWifiNetwork = new forceWifiNetwork(this);


        try {
            myWifiNetwork.cellConnect();
            if (myWifiNetwork.mWifiNetwork == null) {
                Log.i("onCreate", "mWifiNetwork is null");
            } else {
                Log.i("onCreate", "mWifiNetwork is not null");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.i("Error in onCreate","error creating network");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```